# Some algebraic properties of curl

Tags: cross-product, vector-fields

Given vector fields $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf H$ with curl $\mathbf E= - \frac 1 c \frac {\partial \mathbf H} {\partial t}$ 
and curl  $\mathbf H= \frac 1 c \frac {\partial \mathbf E} {\partial t}$ where $c$ is a constant, show the following:

$$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf E ) = - \frac 1 {c^2} \frac {\partial ^2 \mathbf E} {\partial t^2}$$

Thoughts: This is the curl of the curl of $\mathbf E$, which is the same as saying "curl $(-\frac 1 c \frac {\partial \mathbf H} {\partial t})$". I get the feeling I'm supposed to somehow substitute curl $\mathbf H$ for $\mathbf H$, allowing me to get rid of the curl on the outside of the parentheses. But I'm not sure if/how/why we're allowed to do that- the only reason I'd even suggest this is because the answer seems to fit. Help?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming homogeneous&sourcleless medium, from maxwell equations we have:

$$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf E ) =\nabla \times (-\frac{\partial(\mu \mathbf H)}{\partial t})=-\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla \times \mathbf H=-\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial(\epsilon \mathbf E)}{\partial t}=-\mu \epsilon\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf E}{\partial t^2}= - \frac 1 {c^2} \frac {\partial ^2 \mathbf E} {\partial t^2}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation more specifically https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/4/c/0/4c0e73d35e8c84c9887c8c9433335cbe.png

Comment: Look at it carefully. I never wrote such a thing.

Comment: Oops, nevermind- I totally misread my book. It turns out that it does also use $c$, not $\frac 1 c$ as the speed of light, so your explanation makes sense again.

Comment: Wait, actually, if $c= \frac 1 {\sqrt {\mu_0 \epsilon_0}}$ and $\frac 1 c = \sqrt {\mu_0 \epsilon_0}$, then it's given in the problem that $\nabla \times \mathbf E= -\sqrt {\mu_0 \epsilon_0} \frac {\partial \mathbf H} {\partial t}$. What kinds of algebraic manipulations do we use to get from there to $\nabla \times \mathbf E= -\frac {\partial (\mu \mathbf H)} {\partial t}$?

Comment: Maxwell equations say: $$\nabla \times \mathbf E  =-\mu \frac{\partial \mathbf H}{\partial t}$$ I am sure you misread the question.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the textbook wants me to do it algebraically using only the two given equations

Comment: Substitute $\frac1c=\mu=\epsilon$ You'll find the same result